# Simulate CTRL+F12 2 second keypress

Tags: applescript

Im trying to bring up the OS X shutdown dialogue box by simulating the key press <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd> for 2 seconds (using a logitech keyboard). No matter how much I try I just can not get it to work.

My latest script looks like this:

```
on run
    tell application "System Events"
        key down {key code 111 , key code 59}
        delay 2.0
        key up {key code 111 , key code 59}
    end tell
end run
```

This should work and does work if I press <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd> for 2 seconds on my keyboard, so can someone tell my why it doesn't work when called via applescript?

Comment: Why not make a script which directly calls the shutdown dialogue instead of one that simulates the shortcut that triggers it?

Comment: Thats exactly what i want to do, the two examples below work for shut down and reset respectively but i want to call the event that brings up the same box as ctrl-f12, with the options for "Reset, Sleep, Cancel & Shutdown". does anybody know the correct event name to call ?"loginwindow"

Answer (score 1):

Rather than simulating a keyboard shortcut, you can simply call the shutdown dialog itself with the following AppleScript:

```
tell application "loginwindow" to «event aevtrsdn»
```

…or for the restart dialog:

```
tell application "loginwindow" to «event aevtrrst»
```